# How to get dependency information about a word?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, text-processing

I have already successfully parsed sentences to get dependency information using stanford parser (version 3.9.1(run it in IDE Eclipse）) with command "TypedDependencies", but how could I get depnedency information about a single word( it's parent, siblings and children)?  I have searched javadoc, it seems Class semanticGraph is used to do this job, but it need a IndexedWord type as input, how do I get IndexedWord? Do you have any simple samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `SemanticGraph` from a `List` of `TypedDependencies` and then you can use the methods `getChildren(IndexedWord iw)`, `getParent(IndexedWord iw)`, and `getSiblings(IndexedWord iw)`. (See the javadoc of [`SemanticGraph`](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.html)).

To get the `IndexedWord` of a specific word, you can, for example, use the `SemanticGraph` method `getNodeByIndex(int i)`, which will return the `IndexNode` of the i-th token in a sentence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helpd! But how to get all the word's IndexedWord in a sentence? Cause I need every token's dependency information. I have tried methods - getAllNodesByWordPattern(), there is my code "Collection<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependencies(); List<IndexedWord> id = sg.getAllNodesByWordsPattern(tdl.toString()); for(IndexedWord i : id){System.out.println(sg.getChildren(i));}", It give a wrong output"Illegal character range near index 10". I'm very poor in java, Thanks for your help again!

Comment: I am an idiot :D, tdl.size() and for loop can solve the upper question.

Comment: But still look foward if you have a better way to solve the problem :)